# Retaining count values between blocks

Tags: tex-core

How can one make a count retain values between different blocks e.g in nested loops? For example

```
\newcommand\example
{%
  \newcount\N
  \loop
    {\loop
      \the\N\quad
      \ifnum\N<5
        \advance\N by 1
        \repeat
    }%

    \the\N

    \ifnum\N<5
      \advance\N by 1
      \repeat
}
```

will return

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0
1 2 3 4 5
1
2 3 4 5
2
3 4 5
3
4 5
4
5
5
```

How can the retention of the value of `\N`, and consequently, an output like this be achieved?

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
5
```

Comment: Define the counter outside the loop and then just change it within the loop?

Comment: Isn't it already defined outside the loop?

Comment: Also, is the correct term count or counter?

Comment: `\newcount` isn't global, but `\newcounter` and `\setcounter` etc. have global values. You shouldn't use a `\newcount(er)` command in loop.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\newcount` _is_ global (check `\count10` to see this)

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, you're right. I should have written that setting counter values isn't global. The definition itself is global of course

Comment: @koralakralj TeX uses count, LaTeX uses counter ....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer perhaps the wording of your comment could prove misleading to newcomers. A `counter` is a LaTeX thing, and setting counter values _is_ global. In TeX there are no counters, only  count's, and setting a count isn't global.

Comment: @jfbu: I don't see the point. I should rather delete any of my comments ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer "... that setting counter values isn't global ..." there are no counter in TeX, hence you speak LaTeX, and then it _is_ global. But I propose I delete all my comments once you read this one ! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the counter globally.

Note that `\newcount\N` definitely doesn't belong to the replacement text for `\example`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\N
\newcommand\example{%
  \global\N=0
  \loop
    {\loop
     \the\N\quad
     \ifnum\N<5
       \global\advance\N by 1
     \repeat
    }%
  \par
  \the\N\par
  \ifnum\N<5
    \global\advance\N by 1
  \repeat
}

\begin{document}

\example

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `\expandafter` to reach outside the group:

```
\newcount\N
\newcommand\example{%
  \N=0
  \loop
    {\loop
     \the\N\quad
     \ifnum\N<5
       \advance\N by 1
     \repeat
     \expandafter
    }\expandafter\N\the\N\relax
  \par
  \the\N\par
  \ifnum\N<5
    \advance\N by 1
  \repeat
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by replacement text? Should all counters be set globally?

Comment: @koralakralj The body of the definition. In general a counter should be allocated outside the macro that uses it. And no, it's not necessary all counters be set globally, but if you want to retain the value past a group… However, in this case it's possible to do it without global assignments.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to set the value globally in the inner loop then you can define `\nogroup`. The core of this problem is: the `{...}` braces have two meanings: they open and close group and they protect the inner separator for separed parameter. We want to use them (because of second meaning) but without opening/closing group:

```
\newcount\N
\def\nogroup#1{#1}
\def\example
{%
  \loop
    \nogroup{\loop
      \the\N\quad
      \ifnum\N<5
        \advance\N by 1
        \repeat
    }%
    \endgraf
    \the\N
    \endgraf
    \ifnum\N<5
      \advance\N by 1
      \repeat
}
\example

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop not making assignments, hence not needing to wrap an inner loop in a brace pair to avoid overwriting.

I took over your example <strike>exactly</strike> (hmm.. no, we don't want `\newcount\N` done multiple times on each `\example` use!) and only replaced the two `\loop`'s by `\xintloop`. It is designed to remove the braces used to hide the inner `\repeat` hence the count stepping is retained on exit to the outer loop.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}

\newcount\N
\newcommand\example
{%
  \xintloop
    {\xintloop
      \the\N\quad
      \ifnum\N<5
        \advance\N by 1
        \repeat
    }%

    \the\N

    \ifnum\N<5
      \advance\N by 1
      \repeat
}

\example
\end{document}
```

[image]